# Multiple File Upload Ajax Request Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This currently works to upload one file, however when I try to upload more than one file it doesnt work, and it only uploads the first selected file from the browse button. Please help on how to make this accept multiple files selected?

```
    function makeProgress(number){   
      var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");        
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('number', number);
      formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);       
      console.log("form data " + formData);
      $.ajax({
          url : url,
          data : formData,
          processData : false,
          contentType : false,
          type : 'POST',
          success : function(data) {
           FileUploadVisible(true);
           $('#attachmentModal').modal('hide')
           $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
            $("#pbarmain").hide();
            $("#pbar").hide();
            $("#actionPlanDiv").hide();
            setObjectEnabled('#Upload',false);
          },
          error : function(err) {
              FileUploadErrorVisible(true);
          }
     });

        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an object of the formdata and append the files input to it, using a files[] object in a loop...

```
fd = new FormData();    
fls = document.getElementById('uplfiles').files; //length of files... 
for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
   fd.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
}
```

where 'uplfiles' is the name of the files field, replace it with yours... 
this should work, thank me later..

Comment: This didnt seem to work, maybe I am not doing it correctly. Do you mind explaining how I can add the above into my existing code in my initial question?

Comment: my field is called 'file'

                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse <input type="file" id = 'attachmentFileUploadInput' multiple style="display: none;" >

Comment: would you be able to help with this?

Comment: on this line of your code, try changing to this  formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);   - use 'file[]' instead of file, and see if it works.

Comment: since it is actually a files array, then use 'file[]', so that it creates an object of more than one value.

Comment: 2017-04-13 10:15:03.225 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.132 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.gamma.oss.itsmweb.controller.AjaxController.uploadFile(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Comment: does this error mean anything as to why its not working?

Comment: gimme a sec, i'm using php... and its seamless, dont know why you are gettin this error.

Comment: Do you think the issue is the server side java file? As you are using PHP. I have this: 
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{

Comment: Has anyone figured it out ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141666/discussion-between-ra19-and-andaeiii).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="my_uploads" multiple>
```

**JS**

```
// upload img
$('#my_uploads').on('change', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var files = $('#my_uploads').prop('files');

    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append('my_uploads', file);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process-upload.php',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data : formData,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });
});
```